# Pass array to Laravel view in Vue

Tags: arrays, laravel, vue.js

in laravel i have ProdoctController and CategoryController,
im passing the category data with this function:

```
public function view(){
  $category = Category::all();
  return view('admin.product.main',['category'=>$category]);
}
```

its working with normal mode in laravel:

```
<select>
 @foreach(category as categories)
   <option value='{{category->id}}">{{category->name}}</option>
 @endforeach
</select>
```

but in vue js i have a categories:[] in data,
and i want to use this:

```
<select v-model="ProductCategory">
<option v-for="category in categories" :value="categories.id">categories.name</option>
</select>
```

how can i pass the data in categories array?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.data = {!! json_encode([
        'categories' => $categories,
    ]) !!};
</script>

<select v-model="ProductCategory">
    <option v-for="category in window.data.categories" :value="category.id">category.name</option>
</select>
```

First part gets you the categories onto the view in the JavaScript and then Vue will have access to them. I think you should fix your `category/categories` variables, if this is a real code you've been using them not correctly, e.g. when you have a collection of many and when you have only one.